# What do I need for setting up a Shadowrun 3 character sheet on roll20?

Tags: shadowrun, character-sheets, roll20, shadowrun-sr3

I'm trying to set up a Shadowrun 3 game on Roll20, but they only have the Shadowrun 2 character sheet and macros. I'm not clear on everything Shadowrun 3 needs yet — am I able to get away with using the SR2 sheet and macros?

Comment: Using this as a base, could you clarify if there's more that you need? I'm not sure if the present title matches your needs, or if the questions' just "can I use the SR2 one?"

Comment: I can add that Roll20 doesn't still have a character sheet for Shadowrun 3E so this question is yet to be solved. Roll20 currently only have sheets for SR 2E, 5E and Anarchy

Answer (score -2):

Skills work very different in 3rd compared to 2nd. This is when they made the split between Active and Knowledge skills, and split up some 2e skills into multiple 3e skills (particularly most of the combat skills, kind of a big deal for Shadowrun).

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE. Take the tour and take a look at the help center. In order to improve this answer, please add to your answer by addressing what impact that change has on what is filled in on the character sheet in Roll20 and how that influences play (if at all).